# Remove HTML comments from Markdown file

Tags: html, bash, awk, markdown, pandoc

This would come in handy when converting from Markdown to HTML, for example, if one needs to prevent comments from appearing in the final HTML source.

Example input `my.md`:

```
# Contract Cancellation

Dear Contractor X, due to delays in our imports, we would like to ...
<!--
    ... due to a general shortage in the Y market
    TODO make sure to verify this before we include it here
-->
best,
me <!-- ... or should i be more formal here? -->
```

Example output `my-filtered.md`:

```
# Contract Cancellation

Dear Contractor X, due to delays in our imports, we would like to ...

best,
me
```

On Linux, I would do something like this:

```
cat my.md | remove_html_comments > my-filtered.md
```

I am also able to write an AWK script that handles some common cases,
but as I understood, neither AWK nor any other of the common tools for simple text manipulation (like `sed`) are really up to this job. One would need to use an HTML parser.

How to write a proper `remove_html_comments` script, and with what tools?

Comment: Write personal notes to separate files

Comment: i changed the example slightly. there surely are advantages to have comments in-document then in a separate file, especially when there are many revision of it, shared among multiple people working on it.

Comment: What Markdown processor are you using?

Comment: @Chris i am mostly using `pandoc`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I see from your comment that you mostly use Pandoc.

[Pandoc version 2.0](https://pandoc.org/releases.html#pandoc-2.0-29-oct-2017), released October 29, 2017, [adds a new option `--strip-comments`](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/commit/b1ee747a249e0c1b1840222ef77607218157f099). The [related issue](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/2552) provides some context to this change.

Upgrading to the latest version and adding `--strip-comments` to your command should remove HTML comments as part of the conversion process.

Comment: It's nice and clean, but be careful it will not wipe out the comments located in a template file applied to the md.

Answer (score 1):

It might be a bit counter-intuitive, bud i would use a HTML parser.

Example with Python and BeautifulSoup:

```
import sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment

md_input = sys.stdin.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(md_input, "html5lib")

for element in soup(text=lambda text: isinstance(text, Comment)):
    element.extract()

# bs4 wraps the text in <html><head></head><body>…</body></html>,
# so we need to extract it:

output = "".join(map(str, soup.find("body").contents))

print(output)
```

Output:

```
$ cat my.md | python md.py 
# Contract Cancellation

Dear Contractor X, due to delays in our imports, we would like to ...

best,
me
```

It shouldn't break any other HTML you might have in your .md files (it might change the code formatting a bit, but not it's meaning):

[image]

Of course test it thouroughly if you decide to use it.

Edit – Try it out online here: https://repl.it/NQgG (input is read from input.md, not stdin)

Answer (score 1):

This **awk** should work

```
$ awk -v FS="" '{ for(i=1; i<=NF; i++){if($i$(i+1)$(i+2)$(i+3)=="<!--"){i+=4; p=1} else if(!p && $i!="-->"){printf $i} else if($i$(i+1)$(i+2)=="-->") {i+=3; p=0;} } printf RS}' file
Dear Contractor X, due to delays in our imports, we would like to ...



best,
me
```

For better readability and explanation :

```
awk -v FS=""                                 # Set null as field separator so that each character is treated as a field and it will prevent the formatting as well
    '{ 
        for(i=1; i<=NF; i++)                 # Iterate through each character
        {
            if($i$(i+1)$(i+2)$(i+3)=="<!--") # If combination of 4 chars makes a comment start tag
                {                            # then raise flag p and increment i by 4
                    i+=4; p=1                
                } 
            else if(!p && $i!="-->")         # if p==0 then print the character
                 printf $i 
            else if($i$(i+1)$(i+2)=="-->")   # if combination of 3 fields forms comment close tag 
                {                            # then reset flag and increment i by 3
                    i+=3; p=0;
                }

        } 

        printf RS

        }' file
```

Answer (score 0):

If you open it with vim you could do:

```
:%s/<!--\_.\{-}-->//g
```

With _. you allow the regular expression to match all characters even the new line character, the {-} is for making it lazy, otherwise you will lose all content from the first to the last comment.

I have tried to use the same expression on sed but it wont work.

Comment: How is this better than an awk script?

Comment: can't hurt to have this here, but for my purpose (automated building/generating, adding a manual step makes no sense.

Comment: This can also be translated almost 1-to-1 to a `sed` solution, but both of these solutions would only work for comments starting and ending on the same line, if I am not mistaken. Though a more complex `sed` solution for multi-line comments is possible too.
Using a regex though, will always do things wrong in edge cases: escaped tags or tags inside of strings and so on.

Answer (score 0):

my AWK solution, probably more easily to understand then the one of @batMan, at least for high-level devs. the functionality should be about the same.

file *remove_html_comments*:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
# Removes common, simple cases of HTML comments.
#
# Example:
# > cat my.html | remove_html_comments > my-filtered.html
#
# This is usefull for example to pre-parse Markdown before generating
# an HTML or PDF document, to make sure the commented out content
# does not end up in the final document, # not even as a comment
# in source code.
#
# Example:
# > cat my.markdown | remove_html_comments | pandoc -o my-filtered.html
#
# Source: hoijui
# License: CC0 1.0 - https://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/

BEGIN {
    com_lvl = 0;
}

/<!--/ {
    if (com_lvl == 0) {
        line = $0
        sub(/<!--.*/, "", line)
        printf line
    }
    com_lvl = com_lvl + 1
}

com_lvl == 0

/-->/ {
    if (com_lvl == 1) {
        line = $0
        sub(/.*-->/, "", line)
        print line
    }
    com_lvl = com_lvl - 1;
}
```